# Eigen segfault no optimizations Solaris

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, eigen, eigen3

I have the following code:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

struct States 
{
    // Eigen::VectorXd v;
    Eigen::VectorXd v{Eigen::VectorXd::Ones(2)};

    States() {
        // v.resize(2);
        // v << 1, 1;
    }
};

States st;

int main() {}
```

Whenever I build the project under Solaris 11 (with g++4.9), with no optimizations, I get a segfault (core dumped) when running. After some digging and step-by-step debugging I think the faulty line is in
`DenseCoeffBase.h`, inside function `copyPacket`, namely the line 537

```
derived().template writePacket<StoreMode>(index, 
  other.derived().template packet<LoadMode>(index));
```

Command line I used to compile/run: `g++ -std=c++11 -I ./eigen_3.2.2 example.cpp; ./a.out`

Some remarks:

- If I move the declaration `States st;` inside `main()`, it works, no segfault.
- If I uncomment the declaration of `v` in `States` and comment the C++11-style initialization, then use `v.resize(2); v << 1, 1;` inside the constructor, it works
- If I use `-O2` or `-O3` optimizations, it works.
- On all other platforms I tested (Ubuntu 14.04, Debian7, OS X 10.10) it works, no matter the optimization level
- The problem seems to appear only on Solaris, with no optimizations, under g++4.9

**The questions I have are the following:**

1. Is the code I wrote correct? Namely, can I safely use `C++11`-style in-class initialization, or should I just declare the vector then resize it in the constructor?
2. If my code is correct, did anyone bumped into this issue? (I know it is highly highly unlikely but I still ask :) )

PS: I use Eigen 3.2.2 (although the issue appears on 3.2.1 also)

I would appreciate if anyone can tell me if can build/run the program on Solaris11 (no matter the compiler)

Comment: What if you change `Eigen::VectorXd v{Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(2)};` to `Eigen::VectorXd v = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(2);`? It's possible the braced init list is matching a constructor you don't expect it to.

Comment: No, same thing unfortunately. I am pretty sure the right copy ctor is called (e.g., can replace the Zero(2) with Ones(2) just to make sure that it is initializing it with ones, and it does, on any other platform or even on Solaris with -O turned on).

Comment: Hmm, try a few things like printing out the size before you `v << 1,2;`. And is `operator<<` like `vector::push_back`? Meaning, does it allocate room, or does it write to existing elements (I'm guessing the latter). So it seems your `VectorXd` is somehow smaller than 2 elements when you call `<<` on it.

Comment: Hmm, will try now. The `<<` operator is not like push_back, you gotta allocate before. But the copy ctor should allocate, that's what I think. Will see now...Ohh, and I even removed the insertion, and still get the segfault, see the updated example.

Comment: @Praetorian the problem is in the copy ctor, the ctor is not even executed, i.e. if I put a `cout` inside the ctor as it is now, the line is not reached. I can even remove the ctor altogether, still segfault. So my guess is that something is happening at the initialization line, although it is extremely weird, since the issue is non-existent on any other platform. It may be an Eigen issue.

Comment: This looks like valid C++11 to me -- and I don't have a clue what could actually go wrong there. Does moving the initialization to the constructor make a difference? i.e. `States() : v(Eigen::VectorXd::Ones(2) { }`.

Comment: @chtz No, still the same segfault. I guess I'm not gonna bother too much about those issues on Solaris.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm seeing the same thing using gcc 5.4.0 with optimizations turned off on ARM.

Comment: @anorm No, I filled a bug, but I don't really think anything happened since. Now this becomes a bit more stringent, as you're seeing it on ARM, which I guess is more widespread than Solaris. Are you getting the segfault for the exact code snippet I posted?

Comment: @vsoftco No, haven't tested. Occured to me when I turned off optimizations to do debugging on something else. Spent quite some time before I figured out that it wasn't actually failing in the code a was trying to find another segfault in :-)