# Eigen SIGSEGV on Solaris gcc 4.9.0 with debug flags on

Tags: c++, solaris, eigen

I am compiling the unit tests (via GoogleTests) for my program and whenever I try to compile in DEBUG mode on Solaris 11.3 with Eigen 3.2.x, I'm getting this SIGSEGV error then core dump when running the program in `gdb`:

> (gdb) r
>
> ...
>
> [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled] [New Thread 1 (LWP 1)]
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. [Switching to
>   Thread 1 (LWP 1)] 0x0830fc30 in
>   Eigen::internal::ploadu (
>       from=0xfeffe5a0) at ./eigen/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/Complex.h:307 307 {
>   EIGEN_DEBUG_UNALIGNED_LOAD return Packet1cd(ploadu((const
>   double*)from)); }
>
> (gdb)

When print `from` in `gdb` this is what I'm getting:

> gdb p from: (const std::complex< double > *) 0xfeffe5a0

This SIGSEGV only on Solaris, and only when compiling with `-Og`. I've compiled and tested it on multiple other OSes and there are no issues whatsoever. Is this a known issue? It looks it has to do with some SSE optimizations and alignments, however I cannot pinpoint what exactly is going on.

Comment: can you print the value of `from` ? it seems that the alignment is not enough for the `double *` cast.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'll try, I'm running on a virtual machine and compiling it is painfully slow.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, I know, but have to recompile first :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah, I know, but I'm trying to make sure my stuff is super portable.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `gdb p from: (const std::complex<double> *) 0xfeffe5a0`.

Comment: seems properly aligned! would a `reinterpret_cast<const double *>` be better?

Comment: Jean-FrançoisFabre I'd need to edit the Eigen source base, and I'd prefer not to do it (except to test and see if the issue disappears). I'll wait to see if @ggael has any comments about this. Meanwhile I'll try to come up with a minimal example.

Comment: What is your exact Eigen version? The newest 3.2 release is 3.2.10 (released 2016-10-04). And can you try to provide a [minimal failing example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/), it is a bit hard to guess happens, otherwise.

Comment: @chtz It's Eigen 3.2.10, but it fails with every 3.2.x version (didn't try previous versions). I'm trying to come up with a minimal example. It happens only on Solaris. I've tested it on 3 other OSes (Win/Mac/Linux), each with different versions, and there are no issues whatsoever. Eigen had some issues with Solaris before, see e.g. another question I've asked (and unfortunately I didn't get any answer) with a minimal example, in which Eigen segfaults only on Solaris: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27022190/3093378

Comment: A known issue with Eigen and Solaris is that it is barely tested ... Have you tried if it works with vectorization disabled (compile with `-DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE`)? I'll have a look at the other question.